# How to add more two parameters in (keyup)='keyUp.next($event)' in angular and make it accessible in ts

Tags: angular, rxjs6

This is the HTML tag:
Need to pass two parameters in key up event.

```html
    <div>
      <input type="text" (keyup)='keyUp.next($event, field)'>
    </div>
```

TS: How to get the second parameter **field** to be used in TS code.

```typescript
    ngOnInit() {
    
        fromEvent(this.movieSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    
          // get value
          map((event: any) => {
            return event.target.value;
          })
          // if character length greater then 2
          , filter(res => res.length > 2)
    
          // Time in milliseconds between key events
          , debounceTime(1000)
    
          // If previous query is diffent from current   
          , distinctUntilChanged()
    
          // subscription for response
        ).subscribe((text: string) => {
    
          this.isSearching = true;
    
          this.searchGetCall(text).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log('res', res);
            this.isSearching = false;
            this.apiResponse = res.data;
          }, (err) => {
            this.isSearching = false;
            console.log('error', err);
          });
    
        });
      }
```

How to access parameters in ts code

Comment: What does the `field` variable represent? Is it a variable from the TS controller? Also it's better to use higher order mapping operators like `switchMap` instead of nested subscriptions.

Comment: In your template use: `<input type="text" (keyup)="some_method($event, field)">` and in the ts: `some_method(evt, field) { /* ...rest of your code... */ }`